# Image Watch for c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Is there any tools similar to Image Watch http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e682d542-7ef3-402c-b857-bbfba714f78d for c# in visual studio 2012?

Comment: If there was, you probably would have found it already.

Answer (score 6):

There's this [VS2010 Image Debugger Visualizer](https://imagedebugvisualizer.codeplex.com/) for which [someone has submitted a patch to make it work with VS 2012](https://imagedebugvisualizer.codeplex.com/workitem/8400). Download the 7-Zip package, and extract it to `<Visual Studio 2012 Install Directory>\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers`. For me that was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers`.

If you have Visual Studio 2012 open, make sure you reboot it.

Comment: First of all, thank you. Second, I've tried it, and it supports _System.Drawing.Image_ only. *not* _System.Windows.Control.Image_ (WPF's)

Answer (score 0):

Open source image and bitmap visualizer which works in Visual Studio 2015:

https://github.com/Jaex/ImageVisualizer

Screenshot from it:

[image]